# disable session cookie on tomcat just for some urls

Tags: session, url, cookies, tomcat6

is it possible to disable session cookies on tomcat just for some web-application url patterns?

All the examples i´ve seen so far disables sesssion cookies for the entire web application, via configuration on context.xml.

Just for contextualization,in my scenario I have a BLAZEDS polling channel that I´d like to have cookies ignored.

TKS.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this problem ? Coz I also want to do the same thing for my application.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I know of would be to create a Page Filter to remove the session cookie for those url patterns as the request comes in.